# VB.net Textbox raw text edit

Tags: vb.net

So basically what I need is a line of code that clears all letters and other chars from my raw text. I need to keep numbers and colons(Colon is this ":" without "". I got this code but it removes my colons also.

```
Dim rep As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
        If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1)) Then
            rep += TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = rep
```

Could you tell me what should be changed in order to keep colons also? Thank you for you help and time ^^

Comment: `If IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1.Text.SubString(i,1) OrElse Me.TextBox1.Text.SubString(i,1) = ":"c Then ... save this char`

Answer (score 1):

You may utilize REGEX:

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Dim Pattern As String = "[^0-9\\:]"
    Dim unspupportedRegex As Regex = New Regex(Pattern)
    Dim saida As String = unspupportedRegex.Replace(parm, "")
```

This syntax will allow only what you want.